# How to declare a swift precedencegroup globally?

Tags: swift

I overloaded an operator, and to be able to chain it I added:

```
precedencegroup get {associativity: left}
infix operator ~>: get
```

It works perfectly, except that I have to add above snippet to every file where I use the operator. It's a convenience syntax I wanted to add to the project, but now it becomes more of a hassle to use than just declaring a method with a parameter. How can I make it so I only have to declare the precedence group just once?

Reproducible example:

Create a new (single view application) project, put the following in `Appdelegate.swift` (or in a new file, same result)

```
func ~> (left: String, right: String) -> String {
    return ""
}
precedencegroup Get {associativity: left}
infix operator ~>: Get
```

Then go in `Viewcontroller.swift` and add the following in `viewDidLoad`

```
print(""~>""~>"")
```

Xcode will complain about `"Adjacent operators are in non-associative precedence group 'DefaultPrecedence'"`, even though the operator was put in the precedence group `"Get"`.
Putting the `infix operator ~>: Get` line in `Viewcontroller.swift` resolves this issue and the print line is now valid.

Comment: You should name your precedencegroup starting with am uppercase letter. BTW get is a reserved keyword

Comment: What do you mean declare precedencegroup globally? You can only declare it at file scope.

Comment: @LeoDabus It's only a reserved word within class scope, and precedence groups can only be declared outside of class scopes. I agree it wasn't the best name for it, but it's also just an example. Starting with an uppercase letter made no difference, I still have to declare the infix operator in every file I use it.

Comment: @LeoDabus can you point me to the documentation that explains precedence group scoping? I could not find anything on that.

Comment: Your question it is unclear I just need to declare it once in a single file

Comment: @LeoDabus I have one file with the operator overload, the precedence group and the infix declaration. If I want to use the operator as I defined it in some other file I have to put the infix declaration in that file as well. Is there a way to not have to do that? To only have the three things I listed in a single file and use the operator in all my files without adding the infix declaration everywhere?

Comment: As I said you just need to declare it in a single file in your project. Why it is not working in your project I have no idea. Try isolating the problem creating a new project and see what happen

Comment: @LeoDabus See my edit, I got confused by "You can only declare it at file scope", I thought you meant it was normal that the precedence group for the operator was only set at file scope.

Comment: The problem is related to the second use of your operator in a row print("a" ~> "b") would work.

Comment: @LeoDabus print("a"~>"b") also works without the precedence group and infix declaration, the reason I'm adding those two is to allow chaining. Which works, but for some reason the infix declaration needs to be put in every file I want to use the operator. That's the whole point...